How to get gm -draw text to work on Debian?
Here we are in Debian and
$ gm convert -draw 'text 100,100 abc' in.jpg out.jpg


gm convert: Unable to read font (/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019003l.pfb) [No such file or directory].

We do
aptitude show graphicsmagick

and find not a shred of Recommends: or Suggests: for what package to install.  Nor does
/usr/share/doc/graphicsmagick/README.Debian help.
